# Calculating bundle identifier from identifierForVendor

Tags: ios

Is this possible? From a identifierForVendor string, back-calculate the embedded bundle identifier?

Comment: For what reasons do you need to know this? Curiosity? What do you plan to do with the bundle ID once you get it?

Comment: I want to prevent Cross-Site-Request-Forgery attacks, by enforcing some "same-origin" policy.

Comment: Would generating your own ID and storing it in the keychain work for you? It will remain the same through app installs/deletions/updates.

Comment: Am thinking along this line also. But will like to tie in the bundleID information into the token. Something like JWT

Comment: Then you can use - [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
 - and maybe throw on the app version, and whatever else you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was a way to reverse it, (which I don't think is possible) you wouldn't be able to get the entire bundleID anyway.

[Apple's docs on vendorID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor)

> Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store.
>   If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise
>   apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is
>   calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to
>   be in reverse-DNS format.
>
> On iOS 6, the first two components of the bundle ID are used to
>   generate the vendor ID. if the bundle ID only has a single component,
>   then the entire bundle ID is used.
>
> On IOS 7, all components of the bundle except for the last component
>   are used to generate the vendor ID. If the bundle ID only has a single
>   component, then the entire bundle ID is used.

If you need the bundle ID you can use.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]
```

Comment: Yeap, I read that paragraph also... "the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store". But it was the phrase "calculated based on app's bundle ID" that had me pondering.

Answer (score 1):

No. The `vendorIdentifier` is a UUID; presumably it's some kind of hash of the parts of the bundle ID. And for an App Store-installed app, it's probably not even derived from that.